# Text input unfocused after one character React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var uuid = require('uuid-v4');
// Generate a new UUID
var myUUID = uuid();
// Validate a UUID as proper V4 format
uuid.isUUID(myUUID);  // true

var questionNum = 0;

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        key: uuid(),
        title: "",
        author: "",
        questions: [],
        answers: []
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
  }

  addQuestion = () => {
    questionNum++;
    this.setState({
      questions: this.state.questions.concat(["question","hi"])
    });
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    this.setState({
      answers: this.state.answers.concat(["hello","hi"])
    });
    console.log(this.state.answers);
    console.log(questionNum);
    console.log(this.state.title);
    console.log(this.state.author);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div>
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Quiz Form 2.0</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          </div>

        <div>
          <form>
            <div className="Intro">
              Give your Quiz a title: <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" key={uuid()}/><br/>
              Who's the Author? <input type="text" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange} name="author" key={uuid()}/><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <div className="questions">
              Now let's add some questions... <br/>
              {this.addQuestion}
            </div>
          </form>
          <button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Both of the inputs on my page unfocus after typing only one character. Here's my code, I'm not entirely sure where I am going wrong here, it all worked just fine yesterday.

If there is anything else that you need to know just leave a comment and I will get to it. Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So there's gotta be a componentDidUpdate function or a useEffect Function for functional components that's gotta be running a re-render everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tholle's response is correct. However, you should make some adjustments to how you interact with state. I've reworked your code with comments and included the uuid fix.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        title: "",
        author: "",
        questions: [],
        answers: []
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.addQuestion = this.addQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    // since you'll always have a synthetic event just destructure the target
    const { checked, name, type, value } = target;
    const val = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: val
    });
  }

  addQuestion() {
    // never modify state directly -> copy state and modify
    const { answers, questions } = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    // update your answers
    answers.push(["hello", "hi"]);
    // update your questions
    questions.push(["question", "hi"]);
    // now update state
    this.setState({
      answers,
      questions
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);        
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Quiz Form 2.0</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <form>
            <div className="Intro">
              Give your Quiz a title: <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} name="title" /><br/>
              Who's the Author? <input type="text" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange} name="author" /><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <div className="questions">
              Now let's add some questions... <br/>
              {this.addQuestion}
            </div>
          </form>
          <button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Actually, there seems to be something wrong here. When I click on my "Add Question" button I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Comment: I forgot to bind addQuestion to the correct scope. The example has been updated.

Comment: So if we remove the key then how do we fix the unique key warning?

Answer (score 9):

When the `key` given to a component is changed, the previous one is thrown away and a new component is mounted. You are creating a new key with `uuid()` every render, so each render a new input component is created.

Remove the `key` from your inputs and it will work as expected.

```
<div className="Intro">
  Give your Quiz a title:
  <input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.title}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="title"
  />
  <br/>
  Who's the Author?
  <input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.author}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="author"
  />
  <br/><br/>
</div>
```